# awk segmentation fault (core dumped) when I transpose a file over 12 MB

Tags: awk

I'm using this awk command and it works when my files is 11.5 MB but when my file is 12 MB it does not work:

```
awk -F ";" '
{ 
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; f++) 
        a[NR, f] = $f 
} 
NF > nf { 
    nf = NF 
} 
END { 
    for (f = 1; f <= nf; f++) 
        for (r = 1; r <= NR; r++) 
            printf a[r, f] (r==NR ? RS : FS) 
}' file > results
```

Is there any way I could solve this problem or is there a better solution to split the files?

Comment: What's your OS? What version of awk?

Comment: appears thi mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

Comment: Im using linux ubuntu

Comment: That looks like a very old implementation. Try gawk (GNU awk)

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input/output for us to test with just to make sure we understand what you're trying to do. btw never do `printf a[r, f]` or similar using input data as the first arg to printf, always do `printf "%s", a[r, f]` instead so it doesn't fail cryptically/disastrously when your input data contains printf formatting characters like `%s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could process the file once per column, converting each column to a row as you go:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==1 {
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        ARGV[i] = ARGV[1]
        ARGC++
    }
}
FNR==1 { if (NR>1) print ""; fileNr++ }
{ printf "%s%s", (FNR>1 ? OFS : ""), $fileNr }
END { print "" }

$ cat file
a;b;c
d;e;f

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a;d
b;e
c;f
```

It'll take longer to execute since it reads the input file NF times instead of once, but all it stores in memory is the file name NF times so it won't run out of memory.

Comment: This is the best solution, liked your talent once again  `++`, short and elegant

Answer (score 1):

If you have memory limitations, you can split the file into two or more, transpose segments and paste the results together.

For example, with the input test file

```
1;2;3;4;5
6;7;8;9;10
11;12;13;14;15
16;17;18;19;20
```

we split into two, two lines each to files file_0 and file_1

```
$ split -l 2 -da 1 file file_
```

run your awk command for the pieces

```
$ awk ... file_0 > file_0_tr
$ awk ... file_1 > file_1_tr
```

and paste the results with the same delimiter

```
$ paste -d';' file_0_tr file_1_tr

1;6;11;16
2;7;12;17
3;8;13;18
4;9;14;19
5;10;15;20
```